# Today Date and Password Expirary Date less than 14 Days?

Tags: powershell, notifications, passwords

I want to determine all users from several Domains where the difference between Password expiration date and today date is less than 14 days. Later I want to write a notification mail to all users with powershell. How do I write the Content from Surname to a variable?
Here is my given Code:

```bsh
$datacoll =@()
$domains = "domain1","domain2","domain3"
$expindays = 14
$today = Get-Date
foreach($domain in $domains){

$datacoll += Get-ADUser -Server $domain -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} `
–Properties “SamAccountName”,”mail”,"GivenName","Surname",”pwdLastSet”,”msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed” | where{$_.mail -ne $null} |
Select-Object -Property “SamAccountName”,”mail”,"GivenName","Surname",@{Name=”Password Last Set”;`
Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.”pwdLastSet”)}}, @{Name=”Password Expiry Date”;`
Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.”msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}} 
}
#iterate surname?
# foreach($user in $Surname){
# }

#datacoll output
$datacoll | Export-Csv "C:\pw.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal solution. The 14 days timespan, you achieve with:

```
foreach($user in $datacoll){
    $StartDate=(Get-Date).Date
    $EndDate=([datetime] $user."Password Expiry Date").Date
    $diff = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate).Days
    $firstname = $user.GivenName
    $surname = $user.Surname
#body content in variable for parameter in Send-MailMessage 
    $body = @"
    Dear Sir or Madam,

    Your Password will expire in $diff days, 
    please change your password.

    Sincerely
    IT
    "@
    }
```

Than you can check the `$diff` variable with if, else Statement and send mail to all users with:

```
if($diff -le 14){
Send-MailMessage -from "Helpdesk <helpdesk@noreply.com>" -to "$firstname $surname<$user.mail>" -subject "Password Expiration in $diff days" -smtp "smtpserver" -body $body
}
```

To check multiple Domain Controllers you can define multiple Domain Controller with:

```
$dcs = "domaincontroller1","domaincontroller2","domaincontroller3"
```

And inlcude a foreach Loop.
With the Option `-Server` you can Transfer the Parameter `$i` to achieve all users from all Domain Controllers.
**Hint:** You can only perform this script from your root Domain Controller.

```
foreach($i in $dcs){    
$datacoll += Get-ADUser -Server $i -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and mail -like '*'} `
    –Properties “SamAccountName”,"GivenName","Surname",”mail”,”pwdLastSet”,”msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed” |
    Select-Object -Property “SamAccountName”,"GivenName","Surname",”mail”,@{Name=”Password Last Set”;`
    Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.”pwdLastSet”)}}, @{Name=”Password Expiry Date”;`
    Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.”msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use **DirectoryServices** and **DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** which are part of the .NET framework

You can load .Net assemblies like this using **system.reflection.assembly**

```
[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices") | out-null
```

You then will create a domain context (Connection to AD) and a searcher object that will go through the domain looking for user objects.

I wrote a function to return users that match a range (How close to expiration date) and a Domain. It will then return a array of directory entries so you can get the information you prefer.

```
function Get-ADPasswordExpirationDates(){
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$Domain,
        [int]$Range = 14
    )

    #Call .Net Active Directory Assembies
    [system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices") | out-null
    [system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement") | out-null

    #Get Domain Context
    $Context = new-object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(`
        [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain,`
        $domain
    )

    #Create Searcher Object looking for User Objects
    $Search = new-object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher(`
        new-object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal(`
            $Context
        )
    )

    #Arry Varable for holding return reply
    $Reply = @()

    #For Each User in search
    foreach($Result in $Search.FindAll()){
        #Turn Result into a Directory Entry 
        [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] $Entry = $Result.GetUnderlyingObject()
        #Get Expiration Date
        $Expiration = $Entry.InvokeGet("PasswordExpirationDate")
        #Create a Timespan from Todays date to Expiration date
        $Timespan = $(New-TimeSpan -Start $(get-date) -End $Expiration).Days
        #If days are less then $RANGE add Directory Entry to array
        if($Timespan -lt $Range -and $Timespan -gt -1 ){
            $Reply += $Entry                                   
        }
    }
    return $Reply
}
```

Here is a quick example of how to use it to get information form the directory object.

```
$AlmostExpiredUsers = Get-ADPasswordExpirationDates -domain MyAwesomeDomainName -Range 14
foreach($User in $AlmostExpiredUsers){
    Write-Output "Username : $($user.SamAccountName)`r`nFull Name : $($user.Properties.name)`r`nEmail : $($user.Properties.mail)`r`nExpires : $($user.InvokeGet("PasswordExpirationDate"))`r`n`r`n"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want a Powershell solution.

Comment: This is powershell. Using the .net framework in powershell still is using powershell. Powershell its self relies on the .net framework.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I can run your script without an error but I don't see an Output is LoadWithPartialName deprecated? How do you handle multiple Domains?

Comment: No no its a function. Place the function at top of page. Then call the function. does your user have access to Active DIrectoy? Also LoadWithPartialName is not deprecated...

Comment: I called the function like you said nothing happens, I have only read rights to AD no write rights, maybe because of that I can't create a Domain context?

Answer (score 1):

I use this script to send email to user about there password expiration

```
$MaxPasswordAgeTimeSpan = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Admin user,DC=test,DC=test" -properties PasswordLastSet,
                                                                             PasswordExpired,
                                                                             PasswordNeverExpires,
                                                                             EmailAddress,
                                                                             DisplayName,
                                                                             GivenName,
                                                                             SN | 

foreach {

$UserName = $_.DisplayName
$SN = $_.SN
$Email = $_.EmailAddress
$today = Get-Date
$enc  = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding
$ExpiryDate = $_.PasswordLastSet + $maxPasswordAgeTimeSpan
$DaysLeft = ($ExpiryDate-$today).days

If ($DaysLeft -lt 7 -and $DaysLeft -gt 0)
{
  Send-mailmessage -to  $Email -from noreply@noreply.com -Subject "enter subject" -body "enter body here" -smtpserver x.x.x.x -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc
 }
```

Comment: This solution is only for one Domain, I have multiple Domains. And before I send an E-Mail to users I want to see the users in a csv list for example, can you please help?

Comment: You have multiple domains or multiple domain controller ?

Comment: multiple domain controller, I want the output from all domain controllers.

Comment: If you have multiple domain controller they are synchronizing the same information. If you need to see a example before sending this to the user you could hard code your email in this line  Send-mailmessage -to  "your Email"  -from noreply@noreply.com -Subject "enter subject" -body "enter body here" -smtpserver x.x.x.x -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc

Comment: I actually solved the Problem, every Domain Controller has an other Information,  I am iterating trough different Domain Controllers with the variable $Domains. Thanks at all.